# Can someone explain what it means for$ S^1$ to map to $S^1$ under a function $f$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

If we are trying to get a circle to map onto itself 
through a continuous function $f$,
as shown [here](https://youtu.be/CSC5Q6ULWrg?list=PL6763F57A61FE6FE8&t=66), why is the image of $S^1$ a squiggly line that 'wraps' around the circle?

Comment: @EpsilonSigma: Welcome to Math.SE. :) I didn't watch the video (so am not venturing a proper answer), but presumably the squiggly line is the "domain" copy of $S^{1}$, which you're meant to imagine traced at constant arc length per unit time, and the domain is depicted winding around the "target/codomain" copy of $S^{1}$. If a particular point $p$ on the squiggly curve "lies next to" $q = (\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$, then $f(p) = q$. Hope that's helpful....